# Where do I run spark - Standalone, Hadoop or Mesos

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, mesos

I'm learning Spark but am confused if I have to run spark on Hadoop/Yarn or Mesos.

Is there any performance gain if I run on Hadoop/Mesos ?

Right now, am running just in standalone on a 4 node cluster.

Any experienced user who can provide some guidance here ?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the details of your use case, you may see performance go up and down in any given configuration compared to another. However Hadoop and Mesos give you other advantages than performance. There are many in each case but for example:

Hadoop

- HDFS as a resilient, distributed file store.
- Access data sets using metadata existing in Hadoop, such as through HiveContext
- Mix Spark processing with other methods such as Map-Reduce
- YARN as a resource manager to assign resources to your tasks

Mesos - Mesos is more focussed on a specific role than Hadoop, namely managing resources across a cluster of machines. However it does this across a range of Workload types. These could be data processing jobs such as Spark, distributed applications in Akka,  distributed database etc. It can move tasks to other machines if a one machine fails.

I recommend watching this video, I was lucky enough to attend this meetup live:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzx4-6RB7Yw

It demonstrates the use of Spark, HDFS, Mesos and Docker to do distributed computing on a cluster of Amazon cloud machines.

Comment: One quibble, I would say Mesos is more general, since it can control a wide class of distributed systems that YARN can't, including databases, Kafka, even HDFS itself. That said, you usually pick the clustering solution based on your larger needs, e.g., you're already using Hadoop for other things.  If standalone is currently working for you, I would stick with it, as the other systems have more overhead, but more features.